# apache2 rewrite rule on index.php only works if index.php is typed in

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ redirect.php?s=$1
```

Works with

```
website.com/index.php/something
```

But not with

```
website.com/something
```

Any way to get this to work?

`RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ redirect.php?s=$1` did not do the trick.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)

Comment: I'm fairly sure just removing the slash in the rewrite would solve the problem. Can't test sadly.

Comment: @ErikA Unfortunately that question and it's answer do not help me. All info on there is based on the assumption that there is something between the base url and what to rewrite to. Eg: `RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*)$    /newblog/$1` instead of `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$    /newblog/$1`

Comment: @Sašo Unfortunately, no. That rewrites the **entire** url and not just what comes after the slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably clarify a little more thoroughly what behavior you're looking for, but this is probably close to it..

```
# Don't redirect for /index.php or /index.php/
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ - [L]
# Don't redirect for /redirect.php
RewriteRule ^redirect\.php.* - [L]
# Redirect everything with /index.php/something, keeping everything after index.php/
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+)$ redirect.php?s=$1 [L]
# This request didn't start with one of the PHP files, so just dump the whole thing into the query parameter
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redirect.php?s=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I just want `website.com/something` to rewrite to `redirect.php?s=something`. But as it stands I have to explicitly type out `website.com/index.php/something` or it will not work. Unfortunately your suggestion did not change this behavior. To simplify: This works -> `RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ redirect.php?s=$1` _website.com/test/something_ will rewrite. And this does not work -> `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ redirect.php?s=$1` _website.com/something_ does **not** rewrite. It should.. because I took out "test" in both the rewrite rule and the URL.

Comment: No, it should not work.  You added a leading slash to your pattern, which is not part of the match string in a `<Directory>` or `.htaccess` context.  Remove that slash (as you'll see I did in the rule I provided) and it will work.

Comment: I tried it on a local installation of apache2 and it works fine here. Apparently the host I am using screws up the redirect if the $_GET value ends in **.com**. Works fine with .org etc. Highly strange... but the .htaccess is not to blame, so thank you ;)